# apt-get install of dh-systemd fails due to debhelper, but debhelper is already at the latest version

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, apt-get, dpkg

I am running Ubuntu 16.04.  I'd like to install the `dh-systemd` package.  When I try this with `apt-get`, the following error occurs:

```
  sudo apt-get -f install dh-systemd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 dh-systemd : Depends: debhelper but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

But `apt-get` reports that `debhelper` is at the latest version:

```
 sudo apt-get -f install debhelper
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
debhelper is already the newest version (10.2.2ubuntu1~ubuntu16.04.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

I've tried `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade`, but these errors have not cleared.  I also tried the `-f install`, `--configure -a`, `-f install` sequence recommended on AskUbuntu, but again, no luck.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working by removing `debhelper`, and then installing both `dh-systemd` and `debhelper`:

```
sudo apt-get remove debhelper
sudo apt-get install dh-systemd
sudo apt-get install debhelper -t xenial-backports
```

(The second step installed both `dh-systemd` and `debhelper`, and then last step upgraded `debhelper` and `dh-systemd`, along with a few other packages).